# Windows 7 Drag and Drop does not work, shadow 'hangs'

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

I am seeing a strange issue with my Windows 7 PC. I am trying to drag and drop items (files, folders, shortcuts, emails in outlook 2013) into folders or just around the desktop. When I attempt to do so, the 'drop-shadow' (transparent image of what I am dragging that follows the mouse) remains where I un-clicked the left mouse button, and the file is not moved into the folder.

Here is a picture. Note that my mouse is currently not pressed down anywhere. This problem is apparent in folders, my desktop, and outlook.

Dragging files:

[image: drag and drop]

Moving into a folder:

[image: drag and drop]

Moving around on desktop:

[image: drag and drop]

I have tried with both another mouse and the laptops trackpad. Same issue. My ESC button is not stuck down. I have tried right-click holding the file and pressing esc, and esc then ctrl. I have tried restarting. I have tried exiting every program I can think of on my PC. None of the above have worked.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: First try updating your video drivers to the latest.

Comment: I have checked my drivers, and they are up to date.

Comment: Have you tried (left) clicking after releasing the mouse button? Are you administrator on this system? If so, try creating a new user, logging in as that user, and repeating the test. This looks like it might be a (Control Panel) configuration issue.

Comment: No lie, I restarted and everything worked fine. Then I opened iTunes and it started happening again. I updated iTunes and restarted and I have not seen the problem again. I will watch it for an hour or so for the issue.

Comment: Sorry, what is the proper etiquette to closing issues in this case?

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried another restart and the problem disappeared. I opened iTunes (11.3.0.54) and the problem started happening again. Updating to iTunes 11.4 and restarting my PC again seems to have fixed the issue.